# footer background always to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the footer of my pages. I'd want to have a footer (background) always on the bottom of the page. His height should grow if the browser becomes larger. I've seen stickyfooter but the height doesn't change in that case. Thank you.

http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/2499/layoutus.png

Here is the link to the image to explain better.

Comment: is the footer background an image or just a colour?

Answer (score 1):

Set background color of the body to the background color of the footer, wrap your content in a `div` with preferred background color of your content area.

Answer (score 1):

In your picture the body remains the same, and only the footer is growing; to achieve that, you must specify an fixed height for your body.

If you instead want both of them to grow, this is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="main">I'm the body</div>
<div id="footer">I'm the enlarging footer</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}

#main{    
    background:silver;
    min-height: 80%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}
#footer{    
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 20%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/TyhLL/

Answer (score -1):

I have also gone through the same problem

[sticky footer the flexibleway](http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/)

this post might be very helpful to you.